# How to find the integral $F = \int_a^b \dfrac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x-a}}dx$

Tags: integration

Is there a solution in closed form for the following integral?
\begin{equation}
F = \int_a^b \dfrac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x-a}}\,dx
\end{equation}

Comment: you can type these integrals into wolfram. it even reads most mathjax

Comment: In terms of *elementary functions*, no. But the substitution $x-a=u^2$ turns it into something familiar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the substitution $u^2 = x-a$ as pointed out by André Nicolas in the comments yields $$\int_{0}^{\sqrt{b-a}} e^{a-u^2} \, \mathrm{d}u  = e^{-a}\int_0^{\sqrt{b-a}} e^{-u^2} \, \mathrm{d}u= \sqrt{\pi} \, e^{-a}\text{ erf}\left(\sqrt{b-a}\right)$$

Answer (score 3):

Yes: $$\sqrt{\pi}\; {{\rm e}^{-a}}{\rm erf} \left(\sqrt {b-a}\right)$$

Comment: You are so economic in using words!